# not getting updated value from Notification intent object

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on Android GCM Push Notification. below is my code, in this code i am trying to nevigate my page on two diffrent page on the besis of "redirectUrl" value(i am getting this from gcm)

But when i trying to get intent.getExtras() on my Activity every time it's same (first notification binded value). suppose first notification i have got for navigate to Home page it's working fine but next time if i got notification for Profile Page but it getting Home from getIntent.getExtra() bundle.

**GCMBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action=intent.getAction();
                if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")){
                    //code when device will registered with GCM
                }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
                    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
                    String notificationMessage=intent.getExtras().getString("notificationMessage","");
                    NotificationManager NM=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Message",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    if(alarmSound!=null)
                        notify.sound = alarmSound;
                    String customerID=bundle.getString("customerID","0");
                    String siteID=bundle.getString("siteID","0");
                    PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, getIntent(context,bundle.getString("redirectUrl","")),0);
                    notify.setLatestEventInfo(context,"Message",notificationMessage,pending);
                    notify.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    int i= new Random().nextInt(1000 - 0 + 1);
                    NM.notify(i, notify);
                }
            }
            public Intent getIntent(Context context,String redirectUrl){
                Intent intent=null;
                intent=new Intent(context, AltaDataActivity.class);
                if(redirectUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")){
                    intent.putExtra("selectedSliderID", "Home");
                }else{
                    intent.putExtra("selectedSliderID", "Profile");
                }
                return intent;
            }
        }
```

**Activity**

```
public class AltaDataActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alta_data);
        selectedSliderID="Home";
        Bundle notificationBundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bindedBundleWithIntent!=null){               
            selectedSliderID=notificationBundle.getString("selectedSliderID");
            System.out.println(selectedSliderID);

        }
        //open page on the besis of selectedSliderID value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

problem in line of receiver class

```
PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, getIntent(context,bundle.getString("redirectUrl","")),0);
```

in this line second parameter is requestCode so we should not create pending intent with same request so provide it diffrent for all Pending intent. and last parameter instead  of 0 use

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```